# Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository error when there are 2 users

Tags: git

I am getting the error when I try to push my commit to git.

```
abcuser@abcvm:~/Desktop/try_it-master$ git push origin master
```

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
>   'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts. Permission denied
>   (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

```
abcuser@abcvm:~/Desktop/try_it-master$ git config -l

user.name=venkatabc
user.email=venkatabc@abc.com
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:myproject/gameon.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=venkatxyz
user.email=venkat@xyz.com
```

I don't know what might be the problem. Please help me. 
And from now and future I want to push the code from the user **venkatxyz**.

How to solve this?

Comment: Your git configuration has nothing to do with SSH authentication.

Comment: You need to generate ssh private and public keys and add the public key to the server.

Comment: Already there is an ssh key.

Comment: @1615903 - initially when I added ssh with user.email=venkat@xyz.com and pushed to github, it is pushed with username venkatabc.